What does *Erigor dum corrigor* mean?
Joannis Baptista Ricciolus was a 17th century astronomer who wrote the Almagestum Novum, an updated replacement for Ptolomaeus' Almagestum. This Almagestum Novum has a rather striking frontispiece which shows Ptolomaeus reclining on the ground. His systema mundi, the Ptolomaic model of the universe, lies on the ground at his feet. Argus is holding a telescope to his knee (which has an eye on it!) and is attending Urania, who is weighing two other models of the universe: the Copernican model (left) and the Tychonic model (right).

Ptolomaeus is gazing up expectantly waiting to see which of the two new models will replace his.  The rather gnomic words Erigor dum corrigor issue from his mouth.
What does this mean?
There are plenty of other Latin phrases in the frontispiece, most of it fairly straightforward. Two of the Latin lines are quotes from the Psalms.
The meaning, or rather the meanings, of erigor and corrigor are straightforward and I have linked to them here. Dum is a rather fussy word with lots of meanings depending on the tense, mood, and context. Here the hypotaxis is present indicative as is the main clause. I'm not sure I've ever seen that combination before with dum.
Googling erigor dum corrigor yields several hits:
A. I am enlightened even while being corrected
B. I rise as I correct
C. I am exonerated even as I am corrected
D. I am raised while I am corrected
E. I rise even if I am corrected
Most of these links are behind paywalls, so I cannot link directly to them, and, frankly, I am skeptical of all of them.

my vote: I am raised while I am corrected; First, I believe this is the most straightforward and simple interpretation of the phrase (ask some people what does it mean without providing any context). Second, and more importantly, this very book and its name (novum Almagestum) is itself a manifestation of the correctness of this statement. I can attest this myself: except tiny excerpts, I'v never read Ptolomaeus' texts, but reading some Kepler and some scholars of our times , P is always mostly revered despite presenting a different system. In this sense indeed: erigitur dum corrigitur.
